# Declaring different variables in foreach loop

Tags: php

I know the title of my question may be confusing, but I'm not quite sure how to explain what I'm trying to do concisely.

I am trying to loop through an array of CSVs and load the data into variables with differing names. In my example below, instead of `$foo_data` it would be `$MSFT_data`, `$AAPL_data`, and `$FB_data` in each loop through the `$stocks` array.

```
$stocks = array($msft, $aapl, $fb);

foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
    $fh = fopen($stock, 'r');
    $header = fgetcsv($fh);

    $foo_data = array();
    while ($line = fgetcsv($fh)) {
        $foo_data[] = array_combine($header, $line);
    }

    fclose($fh);
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: what is the error? What is the problem?

Comment: Why not use a 2D-array? `$stock_data[$stock][] = array_combine($header, $line);`

Comment: I'm trying to save data to a differently named variable on each loop through the foreach in my example.

Comment: And so the question is?

Comment: I'm looking for advice on what I can do to accomplish what I've described above...

Comment: That's usually the wrong way to do it. Whenever you think you want to do that, you probably should be using an associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is that you cannot get the variable name, so the script has no way to know that there is an `$msft`, `$aapl`, `$fb`, so you need to pass the name along with the array. The second is that you need variable variables.

Try

```
$stocks = array('MSFT' => $msft, 'AAPL' => $aapl, 'FB' => $fb);
foreach ($stocks as $key=>$stock) {
    $fh = fopen($stock, 'r');
    $header = fgetcsv($fh);

    $varname = $key . '_data';

    $$varname  = array(); //the double $$ will set the var content as variable ($MSFT_data)
    while ($line = fgetcsv($fh)) {
        ${$varname}[] = array_combine($header, $line);

       //the {} are needed to let PHP know that $varname is the name of the variable and not $varname[].
    }

    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: I get the error "Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading" on the line `$$varname[] = array_combine($header, $line);`

Comment: I forgot to add the `{}` around $varname.

Answer (score 0):

```
$MSFT_data = $foo_data[0];
$AAPL_data = $foo_data[1];
$FB_data = $foo_data[2];
```

How does that work for you?